# Bold or normal text on the rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm doing a project and part of is to.

if the line number of the rich text box is odd, I want the text to make bold, else the line number is even number I want write text normal. How can i do this?

Output must be like this:

> **line number 1 (odd)**
>
> line number 2 (even)
>
> **line number 3 (odd)**
>
> line number 4 (even)

*My English is not so good, sorry.*

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use RichTextBox.SelectionFont

Comment: improved formatting, tag removed from title, arranged tags

Answer (score 0):

## Use RichTextBox.SelectionFont

```
int SelectionStart = richtextbox1.SelectionStart; //Start of bold text
int SelectionLenght = richtextbox1.SelectionLength; //End of bold text

// Set font of selected text
// You can use FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic to apply more than one style
richtextbox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richtextbox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

// Set cursor after selected text
richtextbox1.SelectionStart = richtextbox1.SelectionStart + richtextbox1.SelectionLength;
richtextbox1.SelectionLength = 0;
// Set font immediately after selection
richtextbox1.SelectionFont = richtextbox1.Font;

// Reselect previous text
richtexbox1.Select(SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
```

Comment: thanks for your work but I want to do it automatically without selection. The text box automatically make bold odd line number's text when listing data